# JQuery - slideToggle - 3 menu's under 3 div's

Tags: jquery

Right now I've got this 3 menu buttons next to each other, and when you click on 1, 3 links slidedown under it. Clicking on the one next to it will slide up the 3 links, and slide down 3 other ones. (see http://jsfiddle.net/VhPn7/ )

However what I want, is that link 1/2/3 are next to each other, under menu 1/2/3. So if I'd click on menu 2, 1/2/3 slide up, and 4/5/6 slide down, in the exact same place. How would I do that?

Comment: Be careful using element-level selectors (div, ul, li, etc...), as they will potentially interfere with content on the rest of the page. Instead, use class and/or ID selector(s).

Comment: Thanks, I know. Not using this code in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to css the following:

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Also you will have to adjust the item position and sizes if you want to exactly get under the menu.

```
ul {
    left: 10px;   
}

a {
    width: 60px; //or another number, but it should be fixed
}
```

Comment: Do you have the fiddle to demonstrate?